# crossfade duration - what is it?

Tags: music, rhythmbox

What is crossfade duration?

Comment: How is this specifically relevant to computers?  You might consider rewording the question if it is.

Comment: taking a stab i would imagine it to be the amount of time that is faded Out/In when changing tracks.

Answer (score 3):

Generically, crossfade duration is the period of time during which a Media Player fades out one song while fading in the next song.

For example, if crossfade duration is set to 2s, then the music player will fade out song a during the last 2 seconds of the track, while fading in the first 2 seconds of the next track.

Caveat: I say 'generically' because it's actually a little more complicated than that.  When crossfading is enabled, a player will usually fade-out Track A, and fade-in Track b, but the timing for fade-in and fade-out and the slope of the fade-in and fade-out curves may vary, making for slightly different implementations between different media players.

Answer (score 1):

Most multimedia players will make the change from song to song more seemless by fading the next song in ontop; this is crossfading.

Also, some music cd burning programs allow the cd to be burned with a cross-fade between songs.